# How to scroll the scroll view using auto-layouts "constraint with item" formate in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am adding one scrollview programmatically on Viewcontroller using "constraint with item" format and inside that scrollview I have added one UIlabel. So everything is good.

But here I have given "NSLayoutAttributeBottom" between scrollview and label  is "-200" that means scrollview is scrolling up to "200" range on viewcontroller controller, but according to my code it is not scrolling.

As per drag and drop procedure it's ok, I have checked, it's working fine.

Why it's not possible to do it programmatically?

### my code is below:-

```
#import "ViewController4.h"

@interface ViewController4 ()
{
    UIScrollView * scrollView;
    UILabel * label;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController4

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.text = @"Hello World1";
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:label];

    //Applying autolayouts for scrollview
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    //Applying autolayouts for label
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:100.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:-100.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

}
```

In above code i have clearly given NSLayoutAttributeBottom space is "-200" but scroollview is not scrolling what did i do here wrong please help me some and how can i scroll this scrollview